# Docker:Error Response from daemon timeout

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox

I started working on Docker containerization. For that, first of all I installed Oracle Virtual Box on my laptop that has Window 10 home. 
Then setup one Ubuntu on virtual machine and install the docker as well.
So now docker is working fine but I am facing one issue. 
when I am running following command than its giving me error.

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

error screen shot:

[image]

I also read few articles which say it could be due to some internet settings and I tried everything but could not fix.

Comment: Can you run `sudo docker pull hello-world`. If this fails again, it is because you VM doesn't have access to the internet to download the image.

Comment: No, this command is also giving same error. Could you please provide me any reference to set internet for VM, i am using Oracle virtual Box.

Comment: You will need to try a couple of possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=virtual+box+no+internet+access

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having has nothing to do with Docker, but with the configuration of your virtual machine.

The error you are having is because Docker is trying to download the image `hello-world`, but it has not access to the internet.

To solve you issue you need to look for ways to connect your VirtualBox to the internet, there are many links on StackOverflow to help you out, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=virtual+box+no+internet+access